# Is there a way for me to check if two lists share a common element/entry and then declare that shared element as a variable?

Tags: python

I am trying to see if two lists share any common entries. If they do, I would like to save that entry. This is my current code:

```
kwlist = []
for url in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    text = url.get_text()
    if keywords in text:
        links = (url['href'])
        kwlist.append(links)
        '|'.join(kwlist)
colorlist = []
for url in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    text = url.get_text()
    if color in text:
        colorlinks = (url['href'])
        colorlist.append(colorlinks)
        '|'.join(color)
finallink = any(x in kwlist for x in colorlist)
print(finallink)
```

But, my output is:

```
True
```

I would like my output to be the shared entry.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a bit new to programming and I don't know what truthy means. I would like the shared entry between them. But I'm sure that the truthy result would work as well :)

Comment: Not really. I would only want the x(which is undefined until it is in both lists) if it is in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, any() function checks if any element of an iterable is True and returns boolean result (True/False).

If you want to print the shared elements in both lists, you can try the code below:

```
listA = ["a","b","c"]
listB = ["c","d","e"]
share = []
for letter in listA:
    if letter in listB:
        share.append(letter)

print(share)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` operations to find the intersection of the two lists. Here's a somewhat simplified version of your code that creates the lists:

```py
kwlist = []
for url in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    text = url.get_text()
    if keywords in text:
        links = (url['href'])
        kwlist.append(links)
colorlist = []
for url in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    text = url.get_text()
    if color in text:
        colorlinks = (url['href'])
        colorlist.append(colorlinks)

kwset = set(kwlist)
colorset = set(colorlist)
intersection = kwset.intersection(colorset)
```

You didn't show what your `keywords` variable is, but as a note of caution I'd like to point out that if `keywords` is a list you'll have to iterate through it to determine if any of its elements are in `text`.